# shared hosting with only cpanel with java app .WAR file

Tags: java, web-applications, war, cpanel

I have Shared hosting plan (payed plan) Not on godaddy and I develop Order management System for my company -it was Desktop app only -
know it's web app, I used JSP to run it in the browser so I can access my MySQL server local -when the app open in the browser so the DB server well be local server...

now I try to install the .WAR file in public_html directory and it's done over FTP

and change .WAR to .ZIP for extract the file to specific folder

after all I try to access the JSP page

http://XXXXXXXXX/XX.jsp

I build the app with Netbean and Tomcat server 7

but no compiling  or any thing just appear as text file such as :

```html
<%-- Document : newjsp Created on : Jan 5, 2017, 8:12:47 AM Author : Amer --%>

  <%@page import="NMS.NewJFrame" %>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>

      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
      </head>

      <body>
        <%@ page import="NMS.NewJFrame" %>

          <% NewJFrame amer=n ew NewJFrame(); amer.setVisible(true); %>
      </body>

      </html>
```

so ...
there is any way to run java app hosting server over Cpanel with Apache Handler or any other way .

Comment: When you signed up for this hosting plan, did you even bother to ask whether they support Java web apps? Next time you'll know better.

Answer (score 0):

You need a

> Servlet and JSP Server serving Java technologies. 
>   Tomcat, GlassFish, WebLogic, etc.

The Apache Handler is only

> HTTP Server

Comment: thank you for reply
so I can't deploy the app in this hosting ?
or I can contact with my server hosting company to add tomcat to my Cpanel as plugin ? I read you can add Tomcat or any service with WHM I receive just A Cpanel username and password and I can't access WHM...

Comment: It depends if you have root acces level and install some JSP Serving Java. Check this [Documentation of how to install tomcat in Cpanel](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Introduction+to+Tomcat)